# How to make letters in a string lowercas, Python

Tags: python, list

I want to make a function that would uncapitalize capitalized letters.

I was thinking I could do
`if x in caps`
where caps is a list of all the capital letters, and I had it return the position in the list that letter is in, I could have it replace itself with the lowercase.

How would I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: @warvariuc it's the solution I thought I'd be using. `if x in caps`, then find which position it had, and reference that against another list and replace it with the letter in the corresponding slot there.

Comment: change the title to reflect your question, not the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use the built in "lower"

```
a = 'aBcDeFg'
print a.lower() # abcdefg
```

If that doesn't work, you can always iterate and then use ord and chr:

```
"".join(
  # if i is between A and Z change it to between a and z
  [chr(ord(i)+32) if 65<= ord(i) <= 90 
  # otherwise leave it as is
  else i for i in a])
```

Comment: That's it - the first thought i've got in my brain :) Seems to be quite obvious - may be he just can't explain what he really want?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to make the string lowercase try:

```
>>> import string
>>> myString = "abcDEfGHiJ"
>>> myString.lower()
'abcdefghij'
```

If you want the index of every lowercase letter (for whatever reason):

```
>>> [pos for pos, let in enumerate(myString) if 65 <= ord(let) <= 90]
[3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this isn't some kind of academic problem, you would use the standard string lower() method.

x.lower()

If it is an exercise, you can flip the character to an int, check if it's in the ASCII upper case letter range, if it is then add 32 to convert it. This of course only works with the ASCII letters.

x = chr(ord(x)+32) if ord(x) > 64 and ord(x) < 91 else x

Not sure what else to say other than the library docs are right here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Also, it's worth noting there really isn't a character types, only numbers and strings, when you're working with one char in a string it's really a string of length 1. Also, don't forget strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a function for this -- str.lower(). http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower

If you really want to write the function yourself, Python's string library has a list of ASCII lowercase letters, but you could exploit the fact that ASCII characters are really just int values and add 32 to each letter that has a value between 65 and 90 (65 = A and 90 = Z in ASCII, but there are a few punctuation values in between Z and a.) No need to parse lists!